# How can I split a video into parts in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

How can I implement automatic video splitting in my Android app such that when the user selects a video from the gallery, the app automatically splits the video into parts of 5 minutes each, saves them in the app cache, and allows for access to the split parts from the cache?

Answer (score 0):

To split or to perform any operation on video or image , you can use FFMPEG in android . Not only android but mostly anywhere like even by terminal also

Using FFMPEG , you need to hit this command

`ffmpeg -i source-file.foo -ss 0 -t 600  first-10-min.m4v`

Explanation :-

`-i` :- It is used to mention your input file path which you mention after this . In above example `source-file.foo` is your input file path

`-ss` :- It is used to seek your current point or you can say you are mentioning starting duration(in seconds) from where it should start . In above example , splitting will start from 0 seconds

`-t` :- It is used to mention total duration of your desired output video . In above example , output file duration will be 600 seconds

`first-10-min.m4v` :- In last you need to mention path along with file name and extension where it will stored

For more information , visit this link

https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit